# What is the significance of General Woundwort injuring his leg?

Tags: richard-adams, watership-down

During the battle of Watership Down towards the end of *Watership Down*, when Bigwig is fighting General Woundwort, Woundwort is injured on his leg:

> He struck out and felt his claws score deeply along the back and haunch. Then the other rabbit, still keeping his grip under Woundwort's shoulder, thrust upwards with his hind legs braced against the floor of the trench. Woundwort, with both forefeet off the ground, was thrown over on his back on the earth pile. He lashed out, but the enemy had already loosed his hold and was beyond his reach.
> Woundwort stood up. He could feel the blood running down the inside of his near foreleg. The muscle was wounded. He could not put his full weight on it. But his own claws, too, were bloody and this blood was not his.
> [...]
> Afraid, listening to Woundwort's approach, Bigwig could hear the uneven movement of his forepaws, almost within striking distance. Instinctively he drew back and as he did so the thought came with the sound. 'The near forepaw's dragging. He can't use it properly.'
> <sub>*Watership Down*, part IV ("Hazel-rah"), chapter 46: " Bigwig Stands His Ground"</sub>

Is there any significance to Woundwort's leg, specifically, being injured?

Answer (score 3):

Woundwort receiving a leg injury serves to emphasize and contrast General Woundwort as a foil to Hazel, who also previously recieved a leg injury. Hazel and Woundwort are paralleled in many ways throughout the narrative of *Watership Down*; they share certain similarities in some ways and are direct opposites in others.

In what ways are Hazel and Woundwort similar?

To start with, they are both the Chief Rabbit of their respective warrens. In this way, the text has already drawn a comparison between them; they're the two examples of Chief Rabbits that was see acting in the book. (The Threarah we don't really get to see in action, and Cowslip's warren doesn't really *have* a Chief Rabbit.) There are significant differences in how they *approach* being Chief Rabbit, but I'll get back to that in a minute.
Woundwort and Hazel are both named after shrubs; many of the other rabbits are named after plants, such as Dandelion and Strawberry, but the only other main character named after a shrub is Captain Holly.

In a less superficial way, Woundwort and Hazel share several personality traits. For instance, they're both ready to directly step in and do the work instead of delegating. We can see this several places with Hazel, such as when he goes to take the does from the farm while Holly is investigating Efrafa, and we can see it in Woundwort by the battle:

> There was not a rabbit in the Owsla but had confidence in Woundwort. As they heard him preparing to go first into the depths of the enemy warren as calmly as though he were looking for dandelions, his officers' spritits rose. It seemed to them quite likely that the place would be given up without any fighting at all. When the general had led the final assault at Nutley Copse he had killed three rabbits underground and no more had dared to oppose him, although there had been some hard tussles in the outer runs the day before.
> <sub>*Watership Down*, part IV ("Hazel-rah"), chapter 46: " Bigwig Stands His Ground"</sub>

They are both intelligent planners who rely on the advice of others. Hazel relies on the advice of Fiver and Blackberry especially, while Woundwort has the Council with advisors selected for their experience.

> When it was no longer possible for Woundwort to be everywhere, the Council was set up. Some of the members came from the Owsla, but others were selected solely for their loyalty or their cunning as advisors. Old Snowdrop was growing deaf, bu no one knew more than he about organizing a warren for safety.
> <sub>*Watership Down*, part III ("Efrafa"), chapter 34: "General Woundwort"</sub>

In their own ways, Hazel and Woundwort are both competent Chief Rabbits, who act on the advice of those who they trust, and are able and willing to do the dirty work themselves. They are at the heads of the two warrens in conflict - Watership Down and Efrafa. However, with those similarities, the text gives us several scenarios where we can see how Hazel and Woundwort are being constrasted in how *different* they are.

One way would be in how they became Chief Rabbit. Woundwort took over by force, killing the old Chief Rabbit and a rival. He forced himself into the position. By contrast, Hazel never really declares himself to be Chief Rabbit - the position is given to him, first by Blackberry, and then gradually accepted by everyone else. He's the leader because he was given it by the others, not because he forced his way into it.

Another contrast is in Woundwort and Hazel's approach to non-rabbits. Hazel rescues a mouse, and then Kehaar, which both end up giving Watership Down and edge over Efrafa; Kehaar fought in the storm, and the mouse alerted them to the arrival of the Efrafans. Woundwort, on the other hand, completely ignores the mice. He actively hopes to kill a weasel or a stoat.

However, these comparisons aside, there are two major points where Hazel and Woundwort as each others' foil is made clear, and those are the injured leg and interacting with humans.

**The leg**

Hazel injures his leg when he's shot with a gun while rescuing the does from the hutch. The other rabbits think he's dead, until Fiver goes and rescues him. Hazel has a limp from then on.

Hazel's limp leads to Woundwort [dismissing him](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/24085/58); obviously a rabbit with a lame leg can't be anyone important. He dismisses the Chief Rabbit of the warren as just a "lame rabbit".

Woundwort's leg is injured when he's battling Bigwig, and leads to Woundwort not being able to overcome Bigwig. Woundwort's leg is injured, and then, very shortly afterwards, he learns that Bigwig is not the Chief Rabbit of the Watership Down warren. If Woundwort hadn't written off Hazel so quickly earlier, it's hinted that Hazel would have continued talking, and perhaps revealed that he was the Chief Rabbit. Instead, Hazel returns to the warren, tells Bigwig to defend the run, and goes to release the dog. Woundwort's dismissal of the rabbit with the injured leg led to Woundwort's leg being injured by fighting Bigwig, who is acting on Hazel's orders.

**The humans**

When we get Woundwort's history, we learn that he was raised by a human after his mother was killed. However, he would bite the human raising him, and eventually, after a conflict with a cat, broke out and escaped.
By contrast, after Hazel releases the dog, he also has a tumble with a cat, and is then rescued by a human. Instead of biting, however, he is docile, and then the humans essentially take him home and release him.

---

These two scenes towards the end of *Watership Down* serve to emphasize the parallels between the two characters of Hazel and General Woundwort, and to show how the characters react differently to similar situations.

Comment: The shrub thing would be very interesting, if true (the Threarah is also named after a shrub), but is [woundwort](https://luontoportti.com/en/t/1127) more of a shrub than, say, [vervain](https://www.americanmeadows.com/perennials/unique-perennials/blue-vervain-verbena-hastata) or [bugloss](https://www.britannica.com/plant/bugloss)? Then of course there's Acorn and Blackberry, and even Laurel the hutch rabbit.